# Regex for splitting String, using whitespace except if inside quotes and brackets

Tags: regex

I am in the process of learning using Regular Expressions and I have created `[\""].+?[\""]|[^ ]+` to split my string `IF "1" + "1"  = "Yes And No" THEN "1" ELSE 0`.
This splits my string nicely as:

- IF
- "1"
- +
- "1"
- =
- "Yes And No"
- Then
- "1"
- ELSE
- 0

Now I would like my regex to split this string `IF ("1" + "1")  = "Yes And No" THEN "1" ELSE 0` using the same rules with quotes and spaces, but then ignoring quotes if they're inside brackets. The string should be split as:

- IF
- ("1" + "1")
- =
- "Yes And No"
- Then
- "1"
- ELSE
- 0

How can I achieve this with Regualar Expressions and with an explanation so I can also learn how it's done?

Comment: You could simply try out https://regex101.com/ and experiment with options which are all thoroughly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the regex: `\([^\)]+?[\)]|[\""].+?[\""]|[^ ]+`

This is basically your regex with another alternative that considers a bracket in the beginning and matches everything until the closing bracket. The rest of the regex is the alternatives, which were defined by you before (e.g. matching the characters in quotation marks and words with space as a delimiter)

The demo can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/L0sC4U/1

*Note that regex101 is a good source to understand regular expression (check the debug view and you can easily post examples here for future questions.

Comment: Thanks for the site recommendation!